# Restrict the client connection in WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have created a WCF service and hosted it in console application. I have 2 client applications which will communicate with that WCF service, now I want to restrict 3 clients to connect to this WCF service.

Is there any way to reject the connection at server side for 3rd client? 
Or is there any way  server can validate the connection before establishing with 
client?

Server side code

```
Uri httpBaseAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/ServiceHost/ServiceHost"); 
studentServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(StudentService.IStudentService), binding, httpBaseAddress); 
studentServiceHost.Open()
```

Comment: Does your client's IP is static?

Comment: yes, url is static, both service and client running on same machine

Comment: Same machine, then as Shiraz bhaiji suggested you have to use Soap header. So you can pass a key and based on value you can differentiate the client.

Comment: Im new in this technology so pasting sample code/app will really help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop 3 Clients from Connection to the service at the same time you can use the maxConnections attribute of the binding, setting it to 2.

If you only want specific Clients to Access Your service. Then you need to set up authentication, see: [WCF self hosting require authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576356/wcf-self-hosting-require-authentication)

Comment: yes, actually , microsoft attack surface analyzer tool detected my namedpipe as security risk, and recommended "ACL must be tighten", so i want to avoid that